# Blackberry:web view not work in eclipse simulateor

Tags: blackberry, webview

i have tried this web view code on my blackberry eclipse simulator. but it does not work. what is the reason for that? Is my code wrong or Doesn't it support the running in the simulator ? please someone help me.

```
public MyScreen()
{   BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
add(browserField);
 browserField.requestContent("http://www.blackberry.com");
 }
}
```

Comment: any error showing ?. MDS ia active ?

Comment: it always show "http://www.blackberry.com/:<br><br> Local connection time out after - 12800" like this.

Comment: then its the problem with that site. try other sites.

Comment: No, it gives same error. i don't know how to fix it. please help me.

Comment: iam using the same code, its works fine for me.

Comment: Are you use it in eclipse simulator???

Comment: on run configurations- under simulator tab- check(tick mark) the MDS-cs

Comment: if you want to use internet on your simulator, then you have to enable the MDS.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project and click Run As then click Run Configuration. Open the Simulator tab then check Launch mobile data System connection Service (MDS-CS). After that, a bat program will run with your simulator, and solve your problem.